# Sheet names office js

Tags: javascript, typescript, office-js

I'm trying to recieve the sheet names in an external Excelfile, but i only get an empty array.

```
async function insertSheets() {
const myFile = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("file");
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (event) => {
Excel.run(async (context) => {
  // Remove the metadata before the base64-encoded string.
  const startIndex = reader.result.toString().indexOf("base64,");
  const workbookContents = reader.result.toString().substr(startIndex + 7);

  // Retrieve the workbook.
  const workbook = context.workbook;
  
  
  // Set up the insert options.
  var options = {
    sheetNamesToInsert: [], // Insert all the worksheets from the source workbook.
    positionType: Excel.WorksheetPositionType.after, // Insert after the `relativeTo` sheet.
    relativeTo: "Sheet1"
  }; // The sheet relative to which the other worksheets will be inserted. Used with `positionType`.

  // Insert the workbook.
  //workbook.insertWorksheetsFromBase64(workbookContents, options);
  var names = context.workbook.names;
  names.load();
  await context.sync();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(workbook.names))
  return context.sync();
  
});
};

// Read the file as a data URL so that we can parse the base64-encoded string.
reader.readAsDataURL(myFile.files[0]);
}
```

The code is mainly from office-js sample code. Any ideas how i can retrieve the sheet names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following script:

```js
async function insertSheets() {
  const myFile = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("file");
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    Excel.run(async (context) => {
      // Remove the metadata before the base64-encoded string.
      const startIndex = reader.result.toString().indexOf("base64,");
      const workbookContents = reader.result.toString().substr(startIndex + 7);
    
      // Retrieve the workbook.
      const workbook = context.workbook;

      // Set up the insert options.
      const options = {
        sheetNamesToInsert: [], // Insert all the worksheets from the source workbook.
        positionType: Excel.WorksheetPositionType.after, // Insert after the `relativeTo` sheet.
        relativeTo: "Sheet1"
      }; // The sheet relative to which the other worksheets will be inserted. Used with `positionType`.
    
      // Insert the workbook.
      const sheetIds = workbook.insertWorksheetsFromBase64(workbookContents, options);
      // have to sync to get the sheetIds loaded
      await context.sync();
      // get the worksheet references by the returned sheetIds
      const worksheets = sheetIds.value.map(uuid => context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(uuid));
      for (const w of worksheets) {
        w.load('name');
      }
      await context.sync();
      const names = worksheets.map(w => w.name); // this is the name array of inserted worksheets
      console.log(names);
    });
  };
    
  // Read the file as a data URL so that we can parse the base64-encoded string.
  reader.readAsDataURL(myFile.files[0]);
}
```

It should print the worksheet names which are just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the collection of worksheets using the items property. Once you've loaded that, then you can iterate through the items to get all sheet names and add them to an array. See the code below:

```
    const wb: Excel.Workbook = context.workbook
    const wbWorksheets: Excel.WorksheetCollection = wb.worksheets
    wbWorksheets.load("items")
    await context.sync()
    let wsItems: Excel.Worksheet[] = wbWorksheets.items
    let newArr: string[] = []
    wsItems.forEach(n=>newArr.push(n.name))
    newArr.forEach(n=>console.log(n))
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. I only get the names in my current workbook.